# hash table/data table/object what should i send in httpwebresponse to the client(a list of tables will be sent to client)

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebresponse

i want to send a list of tables to client side through httpwebresponse.so what should/can i send to the client.
`datatable` containing list.
`hashtable` containing list.
or an `object`.
or anything else.

according to the list i send to the client i will receive data from the client.
i will convert any of above three to `byte array` and send it into the `stream`.
but what should i use.

list is of tables only list no key/value pairs. 
`client is not a web browser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it depends on what the client expects, but JSON usually works well to concisely represent structured data.

> i will convert any of above three to byte array and send it into the
>   stream.

If the client is a web browser, it isn't going to know what to do with a byte array (unless it is sent as a binary type, which doesn't seem appropriate here). Send the data as a string.

The `JavaScriptSerializer` or `DataContractJsonSerializer` are meant for serializing data to JSON.

Comment: the client is not a `webbrowser`.and client has nothing to do with data.when client clicks button, in a `webresponse` i send a list to the client side and `code`(which i have created in client side app) will send tables(data) according to that list i send in `webresponse`.

Comment: Does the client understand .Net types? If so, you could use a binary formatter and serialize whatever object is most convenient. If not, then a string of JSON works well across platforms.

Comment: thanx tim,ok, i think i should just convert string array in byte array and send it in stream to the client side.and then convert it in string array on client side.will it be a good option?

Comment: That sounds fine if it's just a list of strings.